# How to break _.forEach in lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I can't break _.forEach loop, help me to do that.

```
_.forEach(oIncludedFileMap, function (aIncludedFiles, sKey) {
  if(aIncludedFiles == null){
     break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

To finish `lodash#forEach` method use `return false;` statement:

```
_.forEach(oIncludedFileMap, function(aIncludedFiles, sKey) {
  if  (aIncludedFiles == null) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: is `return false` a compulsion? OR will a normal `return` also work?

Comment: @p0k8_ `return` without `false` just terminates the current iteration.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach Quote: Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.

Comment: @p0k8_ If you just write `return` that will implicitly return `undefined`, exactly the same as if the function didn't return at all. There would be no way for Lodash to tell the difference based on the value it receives. `return false` is equivalent to `break` whereas `return` is equivalent to `continue`.